# Why are my UPDATE DATE() queries failing at the WHERE?

Tags: mysql, date

I have struggled with this all evening.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
I need to stay close to the syntax I'm using, obviously corrected to work.

```
UPDATE my_table SET user_date, DATE(NOW()) WHERE user_name = "Bob";
```

Comment: The manual is a really good source of information.

Answer (score 0):

You've missed assignment operator for update field like `user_date=DATE(NOW())`

```
UPDATE my_table SET user_date=DATE(NOW()) 
WHERE user_name = 'Bob';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missing `=` for it

```
UPDATE my_table SET user_date= DATE(NOW()) WHERE user_name = "Bob";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE my_table SET user_date = DATE(NOW()) WHERE user_name = "Bob";
```

Also, `DATE(NOW())` is equivalent to more legible `CURDATE()`.

Comment: Thank you guys... That works.   I'm still confused about when to use parentheses.  And thanks for the RTFM, but the manual is as clear as chowder about this.